# Is the "dpkg -L" command uisng "/var/lib/dpkg/info"?

Tags: debian, package-management, dpkg

When I explored the `/var` folder, I found the `/var/lib/dpkg/info` folder, which interested me.

I made a package with the name `kgdeb`, and I looked for a file that had the `kgdeb` name. I found it, and this file name was `kgdeb.list`. I looked at this file using Vim, and saw that it contained the output of the `dpkg -L kgdeb` command.

Now, I want to know: Is the `dpkg -L` command using `/var/lib/dpkg/info`?

Comment: Try `strace -fe openat dpkg -L kgdeb 2>&1 | grep dpkg/info`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,

```
dpkg -L package
```

uses the list of files stored in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/package.list` (replace `package` as appropriate).

You can add content to a `.list` file to verify:

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg/info
sudo cp zutils.list{,.bak}
echo /some/random/file | sudo tee -a zutils.list
dpkg -L zutils
sudo mv zutils.list{.bak,}
```

(replacing `zutils` throughout with a package you have installed). You’ll see `/some/random/file` listed as belonging to the package, even if the file doesn’t actually exist.